# Whats going on with eclipse, adt-plugin and android-sdk?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

Some days ago I had this problem.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36174

I still have the problem. Before I Run, i'm doing Project -> Clean.

Now, today, I have another problem. Frustrating.
I downloaded this:

```
  http://code.google.com/p/openjleuleu-android-flashlight/
```

(Not only this project, I have this problem by two other Projects)

Now in eclipse I'm doing File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace. The "Browse" and then "Copy projects into workspace".

And now I get this error:

```
  openjleuleu Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one.
  openjleuleu Parser exception for /openjleuleu/AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file.
```

The AndroidManifest.xml is empty.

I have downloaded everything new. (android-sdk, Java, eclipse).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

> Now in eclipse I'm doing File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace

try this:

File -> Import -> General -> Existing projects Into Workspace...

Comment: With the old eclipse, this did not work anymore. I was frustrated and I did not tried it with the new eclipse. It works again.